# Python: Pressing enter calls a piece of code or a function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I recently started coding on Python, one of my first challenges was to create a small script that it will be a Dice, and each time you hit ENTER it should "roll" the dice, and give you a new number.

Creating the dice itself was simple for me, since I used the randint(0,6) which gave me the number.
I'm having trouble is on the pressing ENTER part.
Any advise? Here's my code

```
 from random import randint

print "Simple Dice"

print"Press Enter to Roll Again"
Dado_Actual = randint(1,6)

print"""

 ---------
|         |
|    %d    |
|         |
 ---------
""" %Dado_Actual
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand if your problem is "how to get input from the user?" or "how to repeat that?"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might want to [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get a better idea how to phrase your question. Specifically, you have nothing here that interacts with `Enter` at all: thus it's a little vague and hard to answer without simply writing the code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you just do this with a `while` loop:

```
from random import randint

print "Simple Dice"

print"Press Enter to Roll Again"

s = ''
while s != 'q':
    print"""

     ---------
    |         |
    |    %d    |
    |         |
     ---------
    """ % randint(1,6)
    s = raw_input()
```

Comment: Great! Never thought about this!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple idea for you:

```
import sys

while True:
  print "yes"
  sys.stdin.read(1) # read one byte from terminal
```

Modify to your taste.

Note: on Windows you'll likely need `.read(2)`, because Enter sends `\n\r`, not just an `\n`.